# adb over IP: Unable to connect Sony XPeria Z5 from two PCs at the same time

Tags: android, debugging, adb

**TLDR Questions:**

1. Is `adb connect` allowed to be made multiple times? I didn't find any mentions of that in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb), but maybe it is some well-known thing?
2. Is there any way to run `adb` in verbose mode or is there some logs (on phone or in system journal) where I could find some info for troubleshooting?

**Problem:**

I connect my phone Sony XPeria Z5 Compact E5823 (Android 7.1.1) to the computer and run

```bash
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
CB5A28LH42      device
```

Then I try to connect over TCP/IP (successfully)

```bash
$ adb connect 192.168.0.204:5555
connected to 192.168.0.204:5555

$ adb devices 
List of devices attached
CB5A28LH42      device
192.168.0.204:5555      device
```

Now I go to another computer in the same LAN and try to make the second connection (which is failed).

```bash
$ adb connect 192.168.0.204:5555
failed to connect to 192.168.0.204:5555

$ adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.0.204:5555      offline
```

I did the same things with my other phone (Google Pixel XL, Android 10) and it works fine, both connections work as perfectly.

**What I've tried to fix the problem and it didn't work**

1. Running `adb kill-server` / `adb start-server`
2. Using another USB port/cable to connect to the phone
3. Connect the phone to another computer
4. Check firewall settings on all devices during the test - everything seems fine

Comment: @Robert unfortunately this is not the case. As you could notice, I already have access via wi-fi to my phones. The problem is incapable of connect to the phone twice from different computers. Google Pixel works fine with multiple connections, but Sony Xperia blocks any other connections except the first one.

Comment: adb is not ssh. I think it is not designed to accept multiple connections. BTW: In my opinion your real question is pretty hard to find in your question. I would start first with your actual problem explaining that you have two devices and so on. IN my opinion users who read should have a basic understanding of your problem after having read the first section (or even better the first sentence). Also the title does not reflect that you want to connect from two devices with adb over IP. Also keep in mind that the Sony phone runs a much older Android version (which you forgot to mention).

Comment: And make sure you are using [Windows version of Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) not Python is WSL or a different virtual environment.

Comment: @Robert I had separate "questions" section to make my questions crystal clear, but thank you for advice. I moved it from the end to the beginning. I've also added android versions in the question. As for "adb is not ssh" part, it works perfectly on Google Pixel, so it seems in some sense "adb is ssh" for this phone. Actually, it is fine if only one connection is allowed, then I have question #2. I'm writing some wrapper under adb and would like to properly handle such errors, but I have now idea where `adb` logs are located.